# Summation of operation in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to implement a function that does the operation that you can see in the image:

[image]

But i not sure how to implement the Summation for the moment i doing something like that:

```
def df_operation(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    return ((((abs(df1 - df2)).sum())/((df1+df2).sum()))*100)
```

And the problem is in the summation. If someone can help me.

For example, i have two dataframes like that:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[8, 2],   
               "B":[26, 19]}) 

dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[3,6],   
               "B":[12,17]})
```

Where for the abs operation we will obtain this:

```
   A  B
0  5  14
1  4  2
```

And for the sum:

```
   A   B
0  11  38
1  8   36
```

Finally we do the summation:

```
(25/93) * 100
```

where `25 = 5+14+4+2` and `93 = 11+8+38+36`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there (small) input data and expected output?

Comment: now i put some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.sum().sum()` to sum the dataframe across columns/rows:

```
result = (
    dataframe1.sub(dataframe2).abs().sum().sum()
    / dataframe1.add(dataframe2).sum().sum()
) * 100
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
26.881720430107524
```